# Docker RUN with multiple commands and if conditions

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I do not have much knowledge on docker file. Please help me with below requirement.

I am looking for a docker RUN command as below:

```
RUN set -ex && \
    yum install -y tar gzip && \
    <Other set of commands which includes mkdir, curl, tar>
    rm -vr properties  && \
    if [${arg} == "prod"] then  rm -v conf/args.properties fi
```

This is not working and getting error
  `syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Something you could try is to have your commands on a separate script file and the run that from your dockerfile. I think that'd make more manageable, IMO. That said, you'd loose having it all in the dockerfile

Comment: Thank u for your reply. I am wondering what is the wrong in this syntax or how to write this..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me, that you have missed one or two `;`

If statements in shell need to have a `;` after the condition if the `then` is in the same line.

I have added a second `;` after the rm statement before `fi`.

---

Your code should look like

```
RUN set -ex && \
    yum install -y tar gzip && \
    <Other set of commands which includes mkdir, curl, tar>
    rm -vr properties  && \
    if [ ${arg} == "prod" ]; then  rm -v conf/args.properties; fi
```